# Controlled/Uncontrolled Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Why is `React` complaining about controlled/uncontrolled input? `value` is set to `this.state.text` from the beginning, and `this.state.text` is set in the `constructor` to `''`.

```
import React from 'react';

class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            text: '',
        };

        this.textInput = React.createRef();
    }

    _onClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            text: '',
        });

        this.textInput.current.focus();
    }

    _onKeyDown = (event, search) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
            this.setState({
                text: '',
            });
        }
    }

    _onChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            text: event.target.value,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <span
                    className={'foo'} >
                    <button

                        onClick={() => this._onClick()} />
                    <input
                        ref={this.textInput}
                        className='bar'
                        type='text'
                        value={this.state.text}
                        placeholder='Kittens...'

                        onKeyDown={event => this._onKeyDown(event)}
                        onChange={event => this._onChange(event)} />
                </span>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any other input which has error? I don't see any uncontrolled component here.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that gives rise to the warning? [It seems to work fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/ym5l3v0891).

Comment: @Tholle I do not get the error in the console from a browser, but only when I run `yarn test`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using both `ref={this.textInput}` and `value={this.state.text}` so i think it's complaining about using one approach. Normally we use `ref` for Uncontrolled Component and  for Controlled component we use `value` props and `callbacks` like `onChange`

Comment: Hm... How do I go on then? I need both.

Comment: why you need both ? it's better to use controlled component

Comment: Because I am using the `ref={this.textInput}` in the `onClick`

Comment: i see that if that's the case i suggest you to use uncontrolled component as input will be only handled by DOM not by react

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand correctly. Can you give a code example

Comment: use `<input ref={this.textInput} className='bar'  type='text' placeholder='Kittens...' />` and add `componentDidMount(){this.textInput.current.addEventListener('input', this._onChange);this.textInput.current.addEventListener('keydown', this._onKeyDown)}`

Comment: i was refering  [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html): "In a controlled component, form data is handled by a React component. The alternative is uncontrolled components, where form data is handled by the DOM itself."